# Calling Javascript from C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignalR within an ASP.NET core application but rather than creating the connection and sending/receiving of messages in Javascript I'm trying to do that in C#. So my application can connect to the SignalR hub and sends messages and receives messages. So I'm now wanting to update the UI with the messages to be broadcast. In the connection.On method I am using the following line of code to try to call a Javascript function to display the new message:

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("updateUI", $"{user}: {message}");`

having injected IJSRunTime into my class (updateUI is a Javascript method on the page to update the UI with the new message). The code runs, however, the Javascript function is not being called (I've added a console.log message to confirm that). I'm not using Blazor because I'm trying to have a general service that can be used from both ASP.NET and React.

Any help on how to call Javascript from ASP.NET C# would be appreciated.

Tried a range of measures such as checking the network log putting alart/console.log messages into the function. From the call to InvokeVoidAsync, I expected the named Javascript function to be called.

Comment: If you are tring with a MVC project,don't expect that could work.You should try with sending  messages from outside a hub,please check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: My issue isn't send messages or receiving messages in the hub, it's trying to update the UI from C#. I could write a Blazor component that does this but I was looking for a solution that would work with other types of clients, such as React